# Service Pack 1 for Microsoft Office 2013 install fails

Tags: microsoft-office, service-pack

Even though the Win7 desktop system does have 2013 products (Visio and Lync), trying to install Service Pack 1 for Microsoft Office 2013 fails with:

> Service Pack 1 for Microsoft Office 2013 (KB2817430) 32-Bit Edition
>
> The expected version of the product was not found on the system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fix is to bypass the detection check

> office2013sp1-kb.exe PACKAGE.BYPASS.DETECTION.CHECK=1

Note the parameter is **case sensitive**!